# IIS site and nant/nantcontrib?

Tags: build-automation, nant, nantcontrib

is it possible to manage IIS web applications with NAnt? 
For example stop or start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use [exec](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) task to execute

```
iisreset -stop
iisreset -start
```

**EDIT :** And [this VBS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ea4de7a-591a-48a6-84d8-0145fc594139.mspx?mfr=true) might help for stopping/starting WebApplications under IIS

Here is the accespted solution to stop a website with nant task on IIS :

```
<target name="stopSite"> 
  <exec program="cscript.exe"> 
    <arg value="C:\windows\system32\iisweb.vbs" /> 
    <arg value="/stop" /> 
    <arg value="test" /> 
  </exec> 
</target>
```

Comment: Thank's for reply, but your solution is unsuitable for me. I want stop only one chosen site, not the whole server.

Comment: I add a new link that shows how to stop/start web site on command line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, I found solution with your help: <target name="stopSite">  <exec program="cscript.exe">  <arg value="C:\windows\system32\iisweb.vbs" />  <arg value="/stop" /> <arg value="test" /> </exec>  </target> Please update your answer, so anybody can easily find it

Answer (score 7):

Nant has the servicecontroller task with which you can either stop/start just the Web server or entire IIS, i use it generally to just stop/start the web server.

```
<servicecontroller action="Stop" service="w3svc" 
   timeout="10000" verbose="true" />
```

Documentation available at http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/servicecontroller.html

Comment: But I want stop one site, not the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

If you like using Powershell either on its own or calling a powershell script through Nant this is a breeze.

```
IIS:\>Stop-WebAppPool -Name "DefaultAppPool"
IIS:\>Start-WebAppPool -Name "DefaultAppPool"
```

You can download the snap-in here
http://www.iis.net/download/PowerShell

Some Notes on its use:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

You can also start/stop individual websites.